# how to add password to active each button (php). every button have different password to active

Tags: button, passwords, gpio

please help me with this js code. How to add password to active each button function. (where, $pic = button).

example:

key in password "1234" to active button 1,

key in password "1235" to active button 2,

key in password "1236" to active button 3.

here is the code:-

```html
if ( (is_numeric($pic)) && ($pic <= 7) && ($pic >= 0) ) {

  

  //set the gpio's mode to output  

  system("gpio mode ".$pic." out");



  //reading pin's status

  exec ("gpio read ".$pic, $status, $return );



  //set the gpio to high/low

  if ($status[0] == "0" ) { $status[0] = "1"; }

  else if ($status[0] == "1" ) { $status[0] = "0"; }

  system("gpio write ".$pic." ".$status[0] );
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to achieve - what is the link between passwords and buttons? Also, you have posted a large amount of code - could this be edited down to show only the areas you're having trouble with?

Comment: i want to do automation car parking system where each button needs a password to access it. my problem now is that I do not know how to create the code for a password to activate the button.

Comment: Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some more information about how to get the best answers on Stack Overflow.